# How do I get the index of an item in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

```
var fruits = [ 'apple', 'banana', 'orange' ];
```

how do I find what index of the value "banana" is? (which, of course, is "1").

thanks

Comment: Oops, I misread your post title as "how to get number of items in array". Good that you made it clearer now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As shown here: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/IndexOf

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++)
    {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
var fruits = [ 'apple', 'banana', 'orange' ];
var index = fruits.indexOf('banana');
```

Will return '1'

Comment: >>> is new to me. What does it do? Google is useless for it!

Comment: This should be included at the top of your scripts and basically extends JavaScript to include the method. I am updating my answer with the usage.

Comment: @spender, that is the *unsigned right shift* bitwise operator, in this context, they use it just to ensure that the `length` value is a 32-bit unsigned integer (all bitwise operators internally work with 32-bit ints)...

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in property to return the index of a particular item.  If you need a function then you can use the prototype function as defined by durilai.  But if you just need to find the index you can use this simple code block to return the value:

```
for (var i=0; i<fruits.length; i++)
{
  if (fruits[i] == "banana")
  {
    alert(i);
  }
}
```