# Where is the string in an array?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the index of an item in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457998/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-an-item-in-an-array)
>   [search for element within an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721972/search-for-element-within-an-array)

If I had an array like this:

```
var array = [
    "one",    //element 0
    "two",    //element 1
    "three",  //element 2
    "four",   //element 3
    "five"    //element 4
];
```

I want to look for a given part, let's say `five`.
So I ask the code to tell if `five` is inside `array`.

If it is, then it should tell me that it's position is `4`, or `array[4]`.

Is there any way I could achieve a similar effect?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you make an attempt to find the answer yourself? This is not an unusual situation, and there's a method specifically designed to handle this.

Comment: indexOf is what you want

Comment: @user1689607 there's a method specifically designed for this _on newer browsers_

Comment: In a Collaborative Question and Answer nobody asks the code. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). It is important to try something by yourself and post a specific question related to your code.

Comment: @Alnitak: Yes, but my point is that it's so common, that there exists a method. Such a common situation should present little difficulty in locating a solution if one tries.

Comment: [How do I get the index of an item in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457998/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-an-item-in-an-array)

Comment: @ADC Oh, I always tought I have to write my questions so if someone comes here from google, they will get a less specific answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Use the shim included in that link if you're on an older browser.

Comment: Will be accepted as soon as I can.

Answer (score 3):

```
var array = [
    "one",    //element 0
    "two",    //element 1
    "three",  //element 2
    "four",   //element 3
    "five"    //element 4
];
alert(array.indexOf("five"));
```

this will  alert 4, which is "five"

Answer (score 0):

use compare function of string to look if there is a specific string inside your array